# how to populate a gridview based on a session

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created an empty gridview, and i created an sqldatasource, the select statement is this

```
SELECT S.[ID], S.[Survey_Name], S.[Start_Date], S.[End_Date], C.[Category_Name], S.[Username], S.[Audience] FROM [Survey] S
Inner Join
Category C On S.Category_ID = C.ID Where Username = @Username
```

after that I pick the parameter's source as "Session" and its Session Field as "Username", this session is populated at login time. when i test it, and enter a username it works, but when running the program the gridview is always blank.

EDIT: My aspx.page code.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource 
    ID="SqlDataSource1"
    Runat="server" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT S.[ID], S.[Survey_Name], S.[Start_Date], 
                 S.[End_Date], C.[Category_Name], S.[Username], S.[Audience] 
                 FROM [Survey] S Inner Join Category C 
                      On S.Category_ID = C.ID Where Username = @Username"
    SelectCommandType="Text"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SurveySystemConnectionString %>">
    <SelectParameters>
       <asp:SessionParameter Name="Username" DbType="String" 
            DefaultValue=""  SessionField="username"/>

    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

EDIT: My login button

```
protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblerror.Visible = false;

            SqlConnection conn = DatabaseConnection.GetSurveySystemConnection();             
            string queryString = "SELECT * FROM [Users] WHERE Username=@username AND Password= @password";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, conn);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", UserNameTextBox.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", PasswordTextBox.Text);

            SqlDataReader reader = null;
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.Read())
            {
                Session["Username"] = UserNameTextBox.Text;
                Session["Name"] = (string)reader["name"];
                Session["UserType"] = (string)reader["UserType"];
                Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
            }
Connection.close();
}
```

Comment: make sure the session not null

Comment: How do you define and populate your gridview?

Comment: @BasharKH can you show us how did you populate your grid (code)

Comment: maybe you forget to bind it - you need to show more code than just this sql - this sql is not help for giving answer.

Comment: binding is by an sqldatasource, and that sql code is the select statement in the datasource... what else can i show? I did not bind it manually.

Comment: Just on page_load, I did MySurveysGridView.DataBind();

Comment: You must have missed something, but unless you show us some code we'd only be guessing as to what.

Comment: can you post the code that you tried in Login so that we can find what's going wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     if (Session["username"] != null) {
          string strSQLconnection = "Data Source=dbServer;Initial Catalog=testDB;Integrated Security=True";
          SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strSQLconnection);
          conn.Open();
          SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from table1 where username =" + (string)(Session["username"], sqlConnection);
          SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
          GridView1.DataSource = reader;
          GridView1.DataBind();
     }
}
```

Comment: the IDs im using follow this format = "08F4134", when i run this they tell me incorrect syntax near "f4134"...what could be causing this?

Comment: @BasharKH make sure the data type is nVarchar in database, and for the grid ID=”string” Text=’<%# Bind(“string”)%>’ .. i can't check the code syntax right now but you can get the right syntax from google and try to search about gridview templatefield

Answer (score 0):

Your `SqlDataSource` should be as follows. Please check `SessionField="username"` is correct.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource 
    ID="SqlDataSource1"
    Runat="server" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT S.[ID], S.[Survey_Name], S.[Start_Date], 
                 S.[End_Date], C.[Category_Name], S.[Username], S.[Audience] 
                 FROM [Survey] S Inner Join Category C 
                      On S.Category_ID = C.ID Where Username = @Username"
    SelectCommandType="Text"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:YourConnStringName %>">
    <SelectParameters>
       <asp:SessionParameter Name="Username" DbType="String" 
            DefaultValue=""  SessionField="username"/>

    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**NOTE:** Make sure `SessionParameter` is a `SelectParameter`

Comment: It still shows up blank even though i did this, my session definitely has the username as i put a label on top of the page to display the session contents.

Comment: How about having more than one record per username & password? Use `while(reader.Read()){ //your code; break; }` `exit from while loop after first read`. Debug your code and see.

Comment: Also make sure to set `DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"` for the `GridView`